# My events are not tracking properly

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

My website is LUXOS.COM, We are using symmetry template engine, I want to track my adverts on click event, but problem is these events are not recording in GA, section, since I am using same code and logic on other page and events are recording. Just difference is I am using '{$advert.name} beside direct label.

```
<div class="main-banner">
        <div class="mainBanner" id="ad_{$advert.id}" data="0:{if $advert.timeOut > 0}{$advert.timeOut}{else}{$globalSettings.adverts.inlineTimeOut}{/if}" >
            <div id="main-banner-advert"></div>
            <div id="no-swf" id="ad_{$advert.id}" data="0:{if $advert.timeOut > 0}{$advert.timeOut}{else}{$globalSettings.adverts.inlineTimeOut}{/if}"> <a href="{$advert.url}" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '{$advert.name}', '{$advert.name}', '{$advert.name}']);" title="{$advert.name}"> <img src="/uploads{get_thumb file_id=$advert.altImage }" title="{$advert.name}" alt="{$advert.name}" />
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <noscript>
            <img src="/tracker?id={$advert.id}&amp;js=0&amp;page={$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}" title="{$advert.name}" alt="{$advert.name}" />
        </noscript>
</div>
```

Please can you help me regarding this issue, also I need to track Impression can I do track with GA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your site has two blocks of the Google Analytics tracker. The old version and the new async version. Get rid of the old one that is above the new async code block.

The two trackers cannot be on the same page and really shouldn't even be mixed together on the same site if possilbe.